# System.Web.Routing in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there any replacement for the below code in .NET Core?

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary
{
    {"controller", "Login"},
    {"action", "LogoutSession"}
});
```

Because this code causes an error in ASP.NET Core MVC

> The type or namespace name 'Routing' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

RedirectToRouteResult now lives in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.redirecttorouteresult?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to use that `RouteValueDictionary` class. Found the reference to this class here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.routevaluedictionary?view=aspnetcore-7.0 wich indicates the namespace, assembly and package necessary to use it. So, not in `System.Web.Routing` anymore. I installed the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions package in my project and it worked. Hope it helps you or anyone else here.